# how to search child documents with the same parent id in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

mapping:

```
    {
      "mappings": {
        "branch": {},
        "employee": {
          "_parent": {
            "type": "branch"
          }
        }
      }
   }
```

documents of branch:

```
{ "index": { "_id": "london" }}
{ "name": "London Westminster", "city": "London", "country": "UK" }
{ "index": { "_id": "liverpool" }}
{ "name": "Liverpool Central", "city": "Liverpool", "country": "UK" }
{ "index": { "_id": "paris" }}
{ "name": "Champs Élysées", "city": "Paris", "country": "France" }
```

documents of employee:

```
{ "index": { "_id": 1, "parent": "london" }}
{ "name": "Alice Smith", "dob": "1970-10-24", "hobby": "hiking" }

{ "index": { "_id": 2, "parent": "london" }}
{ "name": "Mark Thomas", "dob": "1982-05-16", "hobby": "diving" }

{ "index": { "_id": 3, "parent": "liverpool" }}
{ "name": "Barry Smith", "dob": "1979-04-01", "hobby": "hiking" }

{ "index": { "_id": 4, "parent": "paris" }}
{ "name": "Adrien Grand", "dob": "1987-05-11", "hobby": "horses" }
```

I want to find which documents have parent id `london` ,I tried the following query:

```
    {
    "query":{
       "has_parent":{
         "type":"branch",
         "query":{
           "term":{
               "_parent":"london"
           }
         } 
       }
     }

}
```

but ES return no results.how to search child documents with the same parent id in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `has_parent` in not valid in the OP .There is no field called parent in the `branch` type .

Below is an example of valid query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "branch", 
      "query": {
        "ids": {
             "values" : ["london"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This problem has been bothering me for serval days.Can you help me out ？@keety  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886939/add-highlight-does-not-work-with-has-child-query-in-elasticsearch-2-3-3

Comment: sure will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for keety's answer above.I add the java api for the query:

```
HasParentQueryBuilder  hpqb=QueryBuilders
                            .hasParentQuery("branch",QueryBuilders.idsQuery()
                            .ids("london"));
```

Hope it can be helpful if you have the same question.