# add highlight does not work with has_child query in Elasticsearch 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch

When I use hasChildQuery,everything works OK.But when I add `addHighlightedField()` method,it does not work.The following is my code:

```
TermsLookupQueryBuilder terms = QueryBuilders.termsLookupQuery("uuid")
                .lookupIndex("bropen_framework_core_security_user").lookupType("user").lookupId("5")
                .lookupPath("uuids");


HasChildQueryBuilder bookNameQuery = QueryBuilders.hasChildQuery("process",
                QueryBuilders.hasChildQuery("permission", terms));


SearchResponse searchResponse1 = client
                .prepareSearch()
                //.addHighlightedField("_all")
                .setQuery(hasChildQuery)
                .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders
                               .queryStringQuery(query.toString()))
                .setFrom(0)
                .setSize(1000)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

Exception information:

```
RemoteTransportException[[node-224][192.168.0.224:9300]   [indices:data/read/search[phase/fetch/id]]]; nested: FetchPhaseExecutionException[Fetch Failed [Failed to highlight 
field [_all]]]; 
nested: IllegalStateException[can't load global ordinals for 
reader of type: class 
org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.WeightedSpanTermExtractor
$DelegatingLeafReader must be a  DirectoryReader];
```

I want to highlight all the field,how to achieve that？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the bug specified in the git [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14999) here .
The workaround as mentioned in the thread is to specify it in `highlight_query`

Example :

```
PUT test
{
   "mappings": {
      "my_parent": {
         "_all": {
            "store": true
         }
      },
      "my_child": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "my_parent"
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT test/my_parent/1 
{
  "text": "This is a parent document"
}

PUT test/my_child/2?parent=1 
{
  "text": "This is a child document"
}

POST test/my_parent/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "my_child",
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "text": "child document"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "_all": "parent"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "highlight": {
      "fields": {
         "_all": {}
      },
      "highlight_query": {
         "match": {
            "_all": "parent"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Results :

```
  {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "my_parent",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.016466,
            "_source": {
               "text": "This is a parent document"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "_all": [
                  "This is a <em>parent</em> document "
               ]
            }
         }
```

In Java Client you should be able to achieve it via this [api](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/2.1.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.html#setHighlighterQuery-org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder-)